# globalThis is not defined in IE 11

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, polyfills

Sorry for my English.
My Vue.js project has an error in IE 11 and other old browsers:

> `globalThis` is not defined.

Perhaps, one of the libraries that I use includes the JS `globalThis` variable.

In package.json I have this:

```json
"browserslist": [
    "> 0.2%, not dead"
]
```

The `npx browserslist` command shows me that IE 11 persists in the browser list.

I can't understand why Babel doesn't replace `globalThis` via polyfill for IE 11.

Comment: It seems babel is not supporting globalThis yet. Try using some polyfill/shim package for globalThis